# Is there a nicer way to export Azure DevOps project's Templates (fields and states)?

Tags: azure, templates, tfs, migration, devops

I use 'witadmin listfields' command for whole collection, but wondering if I could scale fields/states just to a single project?

The reason behind this: sometimes I migrate TFS project to AzureDevOps existing project. And collecting data about fields takes a lot of manual work. Wondering about the automation of this process...

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to try out below rest api? How did it go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the rest api to get the fields/states of a project. See below:

[Work Item Types Field - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20item%20types%20field/list?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1)

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes/{type}/fields?api-version=4.1
```

[Work Item Type States - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20item%20type%20states/list?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1)

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes/{type}/states?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

For below example, call above rest apis in powershell scripts:

```
[string]$userName = 'domain\username'
[string]$userPassword = 'password'

# Convert to SecureString
[securestring]$secStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $userPassword -AsPlainText -Force

[pscredential]$credOject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $secStringPassword)

$uri = "http://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes/Bug/fields?api-version=4.1"

$invRestMethParams = @{
    Credential = $credOject
    Uri = $uri
    Method = 'Get'
    ContentType = 'application/json'
}
Invoke-RestMethod @invRestMethParams
```